# How to display a popup window within onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt

Tags: android, geolocation, android-webview, android-alertdialog

I had a problem of geolocation permission not appearing in webview and I had to add the following code which automatically gives permission.

```
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, 
                                                           GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) 
            {

                  callback.invoke(origin,true,false);
            }               
       });     
 }
```

All works fine. Now I want to display a custom popup window within this code, rather than giving auto permission.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to create an AlertDialog inside setWebChromeClient. In this case I decided that the user always must confirm if share your location or not.

```
reportingView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
             public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callbackF = callback;
                    final String originF = origin;
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
                    builder.setTitle("Locations");
                    builder.setMessage("MyApp want to know your location")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Share location", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           callbackF.invoke(originF, true, false);
                       }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           callbackF.invoke(originF, false, false);
                       }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                 }
                });
```